# How Apache Ignite WriteBehind FlushSize works?

Tags: caching, ignite

I am working on Ignite Write Behind Cache concept.
I have WriteBehindBatchSize as 3 and WriteBehindFlushSize as 3.

I am puting total 6 data in cache.
so after puting 4 data, batch of 3 data is going to writeAll method of CacheStore.
Again batch of 3 data should go to writeAll method.

But after first calling writeAll method, next batch of 1 data is going to writeAll mehod 3 times.

Can you explain how the WriteBehindBatchSize is working?

Comment: Is your cache distributed? Cache updates store from different nodes, so when you insert several entries, they are generally split across these nodes and therefore don't end up in a single batch.